# My nursery bought marigold is dying

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, container-gardening

I bought this marigold from a local nursery and it looked fine for a few days but after about a week it is starting to wilt. I have cut off the dried flowers and stems and it looks like this. Is there any hope? I stay in India so the weather is dry and hot. It gets its sunlight and regular water every two days. Please advise[image][image]

Comment: Can someone please advise